# Why isn't the up/downvote ratio visible to everyone when the information is available anyway?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, profile-page, voting, down-votes

Low rep users can't see how many downvotes/upvotes a question or answer got, they can only see the total score.

Except they actually can. They can go to the poster's profile, click the `reputation` tab, and see downvotes and upvotes there.

This is a rather inconvenient and boring way to do it, but the information *is* available.

So if the information is available anyway, why not:

**1. Give low-rep users the ability to see the ratio.**

or

**2. Prevent low-rep users from seeing the downvotes in the `reputation` tab of the profile.**

If one of these was implemented, the system would be consistent.

**Why is this information hidden from low-rep users on the question itself, but available if they go to the poster's profile?**