# Why can I still see vote counts in spite of having dropped below 1000 reputation? (And the other way around.)

Tags: bug, reputation, android-app, privileges, vote-count

I know from these [answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67847/can-you-lose-an-ability-if-your-reputation-falls-below-a-threshold?rq=1) that privileges are lost after dropping below the threshold for required reputation.

I've done that, and kept my privilege, though.

I used to have more than 1000 reputation on Meta SE, but I've now dropped below 1000 due to starting bounties.

However, I can still [see vote counts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user) in the Android app.

[image]

If I understand correctly, I should no longer be able to see that. I've tried with a number of posts, and it appears that I can still see vote counts everywhere on Meta SE.

Of course, I don't personally mind that I still have this privilege, and I'm not complaining. But I thought I'd report it.

FWIW, I tested this with my iPad too, and it does *not* appear to be a problem in the iOS app.

**Update:** I've now confirmed that this goes the other way around as well (when you gain 1000). See my answer for details.

I have 1.0.85 of the app, which is currently the latest version in the Play Store.

Comment: Probably caching. The app most likely cache the reputation, and it wasn't yet synchronised. Enjoy the privilege! :)

Comment: So this would mean that the Android app has different and perhaps slower caching than the iOS and Web versions? Yeah, thanks, I'll be enjoying the privilege :) I'm working on compiling a database containing the scores of all the posts by @ShadowWizard for future reference. :)

Comment: Well, can't really tell, but as for the web version I can tell for sure that it's always 100% synchronised. You can try force-closing the app on your device, maybe when you'll open it again it will get fresh data from the server. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, that did it.

Comment: On the web interface, you can just install [a user script](http://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep) to view the vote counts at any rep, anyway.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Right. [The information is publicly available](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279642/why-isnt-the-up-downvote-ratio-visible-to-everyone-when-the-information-is-avai) after all. :) It just takes a computer to find it all and put it together.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Thank you so much for the link, BTW. The Chrome extension is awesome. It seems to work everywhere, but somehow not on Ask Ubuntu meta, lol. (It works on normal AU, just not on meta.) But it works on other meta sites. Funny. Anyway, thanks a bunch.

Comment: Odd, the user script version works for me on meta.AU too. You might want to report that to the developer; I'm 99% sure that means there's a missing or malformed `match` pattern in the manifest. (The 1% chance is that your Chrome is just randomly flaking out.)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Yeah. I did report it to the developer already.

Answer (score 3):

Shadow Wizard suggested force closing the app via Android settings and then starting the app again. This lost me the ability too see vote counts. This indicates to me that the app loads this privilege when you start it, and won't update until you restart the app.

Interestingly, I'm now above 1000 again, but the privilege doesn't work yet in the Android app. Looks like it goes both ways. I'll have to restart the app once more to once again get the privilege to work. This way (up) is obviously a slightly more serious issue since **way** more users are likely to encounter it.

Comment: Yeah, this proves the app keeps it in some local memory only storage, aka cache.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Interestingly, I'm now above 1000 again, but the privilege doesn't work yet in the Android app. Looks like it goes both ways. I'll have to restart the app once more to once again get the privilege.

Comment: Yeah, it goes both ways... might be a bug though. :/

Comment: @ShadowWizard Sure. The second way (up) is more serious, because it obviously applies to a lot more people.

Comment: True, though maybe (hopefully) for other privileges it's different, i.e. maybe the app is checking the reputation "live", instead of reading from cache.

Comment: @ShadowWizard What other privileges can be utilized from the Android app, though? (I only know about the 3k priviliges which can not be utilized from the Android app AFAIK, so I'm asking.)

Comment: Editing, closing. (can't reopen or delete though.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard You're right. I have 2200 rep on SF&F, maybe I should hand out a 300 bounty just to test it the edit part. In any case, I'll test it the next time I'm approaching edit or close-vote priviliges on any site.

Comment: lol, well keep us updated! :-)